# PHP UTF-8 Configuration

Tags: php, configuration, character-encoding

I am configuring my Apache/2.2.17 server with PHP 5.3.5. My goal is to create a clean configuration which defaults to the content-type `UTF-8`.

*php.ini*:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
default_mimetype = "application/xhtml+xml"
```

I receive:

```
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml
```

but require:

```
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8
```

All Apache's configuration (`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`) solutions seem not to work, and I have restarted Apache after I edited my *php.ini* configuration.

PHP documentation:

> **default_charset** *string*
>   PHP always outputs a character encoding by default in the Content-type: header. To disable sending of the charset, simply set it to be empty.

I've changed the `default_mimetype` field to `text/html` and suddenly, it seems to work: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8`.
Settings the `default_mimetype` back to `application/xhtml+xml` will not send the `charset=UTF-8`. This is *without* any Apache configuration.

Is PHP broken, or have I missed something?

Comment: I would probably recommend to manually set the encoding in your application instead, even though you hate it ;) Makes your application more portable.

Comment: *Content-Encoding* does not specify the content’s character encoding but the [additional content encoding](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.11) that has been applied to the entity body like *gzip* or *deflate*.

Comment: @Gumbo thanks for the pointer. I've accidentally mixed _character-encoding_ and _content-encoding_. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have enabled the `iconv` module and added to *php.ini*:

```
output_handler = ob_iconv_handler
```

This handler adds the correct character-encoding for output to the `Content-Type`, instead of the `default_charset`.

However, you should set `default_mimetype`, or else it puts `Content-Type:;charset=`*character-encoding*.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to set those parameters in apache configuration, not PHP. Edit apache2.conf or .htaccess file for your project:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DefaultType application/xml
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP Doesn't do this... However, you can use Apache to do this.

Assuming the above, you could use

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DefaultType application/xhtml+xml
```

This should appear in your VirtualHost (or server configuration)

Answer (score -1):

Beware that if you set mimetype to "application/xhtml+xml", older versions of Internet Explorer will not render the page, but display a save dialog.

To get around this, you can set the mimetype to "text/html", but this is not valid in XHTML 1.1

You can also use content negotiation to tackle the problem.

Read more here: http://www.webstandards.org/learn/articles/askw3c/sep2003/

If it's an option, I would run with "text/html" and use the HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This way, you can still use XHTML syntax and be valid HTML5 (although not technically valid XHTML of course...)

Comment: Luckily Internet Explorer 6 is my minimal requirement, and your source says it's not recognized up to 6. So I'm safe. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too, but I'm pretty sure I've run into the problem myself, and I have never (in modern times) tested in anything older than IE6, so I would not be at all confident that this is not a problem in IE678...

Comment: And it says "at least up to IE 6.x" with an implicit inclusion of IE6 (look at the table later in the post). Also, the post is from 2003, so this might well be a problem in later versions too...

Comment: However: HTML5 is not used in IE6. So how can I be valid XHTML in IE6?

Comment: You can still use the HTML5 doctype with IE6. It will automatically trigger standards-mode in all browsers :)

Comment: Sure, but it won't be XHTML, would it?

Comment: As far as I know, you can use the HTML5 doctype with XHTML syntax and it will work in IE6 and be valid. Technically, it won't be XHTML, since the doctype specifies it as HTML, but it would still be equally parsable, as long as the parser doesn't choke on the doctype (which it might well do, I guess).

Comment: I would appreciate to get some feedback on why this has been down-voted.