# Cyrillic symbols in INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation

```
$dblocation = "localhost";
$dbname = "xx";
$dbuser = "xx";
$dbpasswd = "xx";
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbcnx);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=utf8_bin"); 
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$about = mysql_real_escape_string($about);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO votes 
(name, about, active) VALUES('".$name."', '".$about."', 1 ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

It works perfectly fine when $name and $about is not cyrillic. But when it's cyrillic - script just adds a row with blank name and about fields. What do?
DB is UTF-8, manual adding rows with phpMyAdmin with cyrillic symbols works perfect, PHP-script is UTF-8, everything's UTF-8.

Comment: Try mysqli_set_charset($dbcnx, 'utf8');  after  $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);   (or mysql_set_charset if you have an old PHP version)

Comment: Show us result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE votes` command.

Comment: Also, `SET COLLATION_CONNECTION` - useless.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: @Adiost, why are you mixing mysql and mysqli?

Comment: Also, ensure that $name and $about contains utf-8 data. `echo strlen($name),iconv_strlen($name,'utf-8');`

Comment: Try... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044030/having-trouble-with-php-mysql-and-utf8/6044073#6044073

Comment: @Johan, wrong, `SET NAMES utf8` it's only what he needs.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `votes` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `about` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `yes` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `no` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `dunno` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `active` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

Comment: Where `$name` is coming from? If from web pages, then you should check if `Content-type` of the page with form is set to something like `text/html;charset=UTF-8` (this can be changed in HTTP headers or meta tags). Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055767/php-utf-8-configuration) to setup encoding in PHP.

Comment: I just tested your code (verbatim, just added values to $name and $about) with Cyrillic text, it worked fine. Database collation was utf8-bin, table collation was utf8-bin, and the varchars that held the text were utf8-bin. 

SQL: http://pastebin.com/FMzSt5Ei

Go edit your table and make sure all those are utf8-bin and try to run your code again.

Comment: @Adiost, well, all should work fine. Ensure that $name and $about contains utf-8 data. echo strlen($name),iconv_strlen($name,'utf-8');

Comment: @Ivan Awww... Thanks, I feel so stupid now...

Comment: @SamT This doesn't look like mysql problem. Most likely *wrong* text encoding is coming from GET/POST request. (See my comment above)

Comment: @Adiost Debug proxy server is your good friend to solve such kind of problems. You'll be able to see what exactly is coming to your script from client side. I like this one http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ (if you are on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have:

1.`header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` or `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

2.mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

3.Set your file's encoding to utf-8 without BOM

Answer (score 0):

Specify character set which should be used by the connection with `mysql_set_charset(...')`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php.

Comment: Ah, just saw the comment above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044030/having-trouble-with-php-mysql-and-utf8/6044073#6044073

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt a lot with the cyrillic and it is tricky indeed. So far in my experience I did not use any COLLATION_CONNECTION. All I do is put, as you did, all possible files in utf8. Then the fields in the DB I put in "utf8_unicode_ci" and I only use the SET NAMES params to set the connection encoding. This should be enough. Mind that the Set names might be tricky, as only a single space in extra and it will not work. I use:

```
define("DBENCODING", "utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES '".DBENCODING."'", $this->connection);
```

I hope I managed to help.